# How to ignore source files in bower

Tags: jquery, git, bower

I'm using bower to install packages and manage dependencies. But bower use git repos and it pulls down all files of package. 
I don't need any development on `jquery` src files but bower pulls down all. also i need `bootstrap` pre-compiled version but bower installs bootstrap with all source codes.

What should i do for ignore source files or pull down minified versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files which are pulled by bower are the decided by the package owner and not the tool. When maintaining a bower package the owner can choose what to include/exclude from the distribution.
You can use [bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer) (do not confuse with bower install), which is described as a:

> "Tool for installing bower dependencies that won't include entire
>   repos"

Comment: i need bootstap and i wrote "bower install bootstrap" now i have all bootstap source files on my projects. And also jquery.

Comment: did you take a look at bower-installer?